# Conexion SQL desde JAVA

Tags: java, sql-server

Quiero conectar mi programa de prueba con la base de datos de mi pc, desde java a sql server 2017.
Ya hice todas las configuraciones, y el test de conexion me da ok, pero en el momento de llamar a la conexion con el programa abierto me arroja un mensaje de error.
Este es el error: [image]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En este caso la imagen sirve de muy poco. Ayudaría más que pongas el código que usas para conectarte y el mensaje de error (ambas cosas en texto). Debes verificar que tienes los `.jar` adecuados de JDBC y en la ruta correcta (o si has agregado las dependencias correctas en caso de usar Maven u otra plataforma para trabajar con dependencias).

Comment: Estás incluyendo el Driver de SQL server en tu proyecto? Eso no lo hará solo, al ser dependencia de Runtime tú debes agregarla. Por que para compilar no es necesario? Gracias al API SQL de Java que abstrae la conexión, statements, resultsets, etc

Comment: Como te menciona Ajeno, debes colocar manualmente el jar, bájalo aquí. https://www.microsoft.com/es-mx/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chicos, gracias por responder... el jar ya estaba instalado en la carpeta libreria, me Di cuenta más tarde que el problema es la versión del jar,  tenía la 7, y no funcionó con el sql 2017, puse la 6.2 y listo, ya conecta perfecto.. Gracias a todos!